# How to change 'date added' to 'date modified' for a bunch of mp3 files?

Tags: itunes, mp3

Straight to the business.
Recently I bought new Mac and unfortunately I didn't correctly import my old music library to iTunes.
I always sort my music by 'Date Added' in iTunes, but since I imported the library wrong the date is now the same for all 2000+ files.
'Date Modified' is pretty much correct though.

The question is: Is there a way to replace 'Date Added' with 'Date Modified'?

Comment: Can you not import your library again, but correctly? That'd be the best option, if possible.

Comment: That would be the best option, but I do not have the old Mac anymore. Nor Time Machine backup.